# @ngrx/effect aborts multiple REST-calls in Angular App

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have the following problem:

Inside a Service I trigger the same ngrx Action in a forEach loop

```
 sensorCategories.forEach(category => {
     if (category === 'power' || category === 'air-flow') {
       this.store.dispatch(new fromEnergyManagementActions.FetchBigWidgetDataAction({ category: category }));
     } else {
       this.store.dispatch(new fromEnergyManagementActions.FetchSmallWidgetDataAction({ category: category }));
     }
 });
```

---

This will then trigger the next side-effect:

```
@Effect()
fetchSmallWidgetData: Observable<Action> = this.actions
    .ofType(fromEnergyManagementActions.FETCH_SMALL_WIDGET_DATA)
    .map(toPayload)
    .switchMap(payload => this.dashboardDataService.fetchSmallWidgetData(payload))
    .map((data: SmallWidgetData) => new fromEnergyManagementActions.FetchSmallWidgetDataSuccessAction(data))
    .catch(error => of(new fromEnergyManagementActions.FetchSmallWidgetDataFailureAction()));
```

---

The method fetchSmallWidgetData from the service will then execute the rest call with the 'new' HttpClient.

Here are the logs:
[image: Browser Logs]

So the problem is, that the ngrx/effect aborts the previous call. I tested it with a timeout in-between. When the timeout is long enough, everything succeeds.

What is your proposal? Is there a best practice, I could use ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: You might want to consider moving the `map` and the `catch` into the `switchMap` (or `mergeMap`). As it is, if an error occurs, your effect will stop working, as the stream returned from `catch` will complete the effect and the framework will be unsubscribed.

Answer (score 7):

This happens because you use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) in your effect. Switch to [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to allow multiple inner subscriptions to be maintained.